# Is it possible to put a page break into an HTML email?

Tags: email, html-email, page-break

I know it's possible to use CSS to add page breaks to web pages, for when they're printed.

I also know CSS support in HTML emails is poor.

So, is there a way to generate a page break when an HTML email is printed?  Or given the variety of email clients out there, is that just a daft question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say do it the standard CSS way. It'll work for some e-mail reading agents. There's no **other** way to hint at page breaks. If it's really important that people can print the message then maybe make the message available through the web too and tell the recipient to print that one.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected.  Have ended up rearranging the email so that the crucial bit (a printable voucher) was at the top.

Answer (score 3):

See [this article](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) on CSS support in HTML emails it gives a list of what is and what is not possible.

Also you can validate your CSS here: http://getfractal.com/ once you have made any changes and it will inform you which clients are compatible.

Comment: granted this is from 2008 but this page is not found now

Comment: I had a newer link bookmarked so I have updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: GetFractal doesn't seem to be running? Their email address bounced.